# .bat files for compiling and running java stuff

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create two bat files. one is c.bat and the other is r.bat

c.bat just contains:

```
cls
javac *.java
```

which will compile all .java files.

in r.bat I have:

```
cls
java *
```

it will not run the class files. I think its because the * in the "java *" line translates to "java Class1.class", "java Class2.class" and so one when it should be "java Class1" and "java Class2" only. (without the extensions) how can I do this? I just started learning these things and I can't find the right answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following loops over all the `.java`files found in `C:\java\stuff` and runs them one after another. The `%%~nf` is formatting the files name to not display the file extension *i.e the java class name*. If you change `java %%~nf` to `echo java %%~nf` you can see exactly what is going on.

```
cls
for "C:\java\stuff" %%f in (*.java) do (
    java %%~nf
)
```

[For](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true): The following options are available:

```
Variable with modifier  Description

%~I                     Expands %I which removes any surrounding 
                        quotation marks ("").
%~fI                    Expands %I to a fully qualified path name.
%~dI                    Expands %I to a drive letter only.
%~pI                    Expands %I to a path only.
%~nI                    Expands %I to a file name only.
%~xI                    Expands %I to a file extension only.
%~sI                    Expands path to contain short names only.
%~aI                    Expands %I to the file attributes of file.
%~tI                    Expands %I to the date and time of file.
%~zI                    Expands %I to the size of file.
%~$PATH:I               Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment 
                        variable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of 
                        the first one found. If the environment variable name is 
                        not defined or the file is not found by the search,
                        this modifier expands to the empty string.
```

Comment: thanks! although i don't know how this does it, it works. i will just find out for myself how it does it, thank you again @sudo_o